# Regex - total length has max but groups can be variable, excluding a period

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a `regex` in `Python` for [Thomson Reuters RIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuters_Instrument_Code) codes. The Equity one has the following rules:

```
regex_ric_equity = re.compile(r'''(
^([A-Z0-9]+)          # root symbol, at least 1 character, not lower case
([a-z]*)              # brokerage, lower case letter(s), optional
(\.[A-Za-z]+)$        # delimiter ("."), and exchange code like "N" for NYSE
)''', re.VERBOSE)
```

Now this works great. Here's the catch. The total length of the entire RIC can be a maximum of 7 characters, but the period doesn't count. The first and third group need at least 1, the second is optional, but they must all total `<= 7`. Can't figure out how to do this.

I tried surrounding the entire thing with parentheses and doing `{2,7}` but that doesn't work because it includes the period, so it looks to match at least 2 periods.

```
regex_ric_equity = re.compile(r'''(
(
^([A-Z0-9]+)          # root symbol, at least 1 character, not lower case
([a-z]*)              # brokerage, lower case letter(s), optional
(\.[A-Za-z]+)$        # delimiter ("."), and exchange code like "N" for NYSE
){2,7}                # max 7 characters, at least 1 root and brokerage
)''', re.VERBOSE)
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT:** I got the RIC rules for Equities from their documentation that I have as a customer of Thomson Reuters, not from the Wikipedia page. Here is the relevant language:

> **Equities**
>
> Equities is a generic term used to cover related instrument types such as Common, Ordinary, Preferred, and other related stock types.
> An equity RIC has several components: the Equity RIC root is in upper case, brokerage characters in lower case (if applicable), and finally an exchange identifier.
>
> - EQUITY ROOT
> - Brokerage Characters (if required)
> - Delimiter(.)
> - Exchange Identifier
>
> The code identifies a particular issuer and may be **a maximum of seven letters or numbers**. Alphabetic roots should be meaningful and, if possible, relate to the issuing organization as a mnemonic, for example, XON for Exxon Corp. There is no requirement for roots to be unique worldwide, so that the same root need not be assigned an issuer for all markets. Roots may be reused in different markets for different issuers; however, roots are not duplicated within one country. Subsidiary companies should have a different root from the parent company.
>
> **Quotes and Exchange Floor Quotes**
>
> The RIC to obtain a Full Quote for an exchange or floor display is as follows:
>
> **Equity Root Example**
>
> Example Format: VOLVb.ST
>
> - VOLV for Volvo
> - Brokerage Characters (if required)
> - Delimiter(.)
> - Exchange Identifier for example, ST for Stockholm Exchange
>
> **Japanese listed securities**
>
> The structure for Japanese listed securities is as follows:
>
> **Equity Root Example**
>
> Example Format: 6501.T
>
> - SICC code 6501 for Hitachi common stock
> - Delimiter (.)
> - Exchange Identifier for example, T for Tokyo Stock Exchange

Comment: Can there be more than one dot?

Comment: Why do you have such weird regex when the linked RIC definition for equities is just: `[A-Z]{1,4}\.[A-Z]{1,2}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the total length can differ based on a character within the pattern itself it, by definition, becomes an irregular pattern and thus outside of the scope of regex.

You could probably concoct a convoluted pattern with heavy back-referencing and lookahead but exploiting the regex engine idiosyncrasies will probably end up slower (not to mention less readable) than just post-processing your matches to see if they match the total allowed RIC length, something like:

```
RIC_PATTERN = re.compile(r"^([A-Z]+)([a-z]*)\.?([A-Za-z]+)$")

def get_ric(source):
    ric = RIC_PATTERN.search(source)
    if ric and sum(len(r) for r in ric.groups()) < 8:
        return ric.groups()  # or return the match itself if you need more info
```

And to test it:

```
print(get_ric("RIC.SE"))     # ('RIC', '', 'SE')
print(get_ric("RICab.SE"))   # ('RIC', 'ab', 'SE')
print(get_ric("R.N"))        # ('R', '', 'N')
print(get_ric("RIClong.SE")) # None
print(get_ric("bad.RIC"))    # None
print(get_ric("RIC..BAD"))   # None
```

That being said, as [wp78de](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8291949/wp78de) suggested, the RIC definition (at least the one on Wikipedia) is not what you're trying to match here.

Comment: "Since the total length can differ based on a character within the pattern itself it, by definition, becomes an irregular pattern and thus outside of the scope of regex."
Why does that make it "irregular"?

Comment: @JoshD - Because matching is dependent more on the content than on the search pattern itself and therefore the pattern differs from case to case. If the pattern has to be adjusted based on the content the pattern is not regular (general).

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add the delimiter to your range. Here is regex link for reference [regex_ric](https://regex101.com/r/J5c8EC/1/).

```
regex_ric_equity = re.compile(r'''
(
^([A-Z0-9]+)          # root symbol, at least 1 character, not lowercase
([a-z]*)              # brokerage, lower case letter(s), optional
(\.[A-Za-z]+)$        # delimiter ("."), and exchange code like "N" for NYSE
){3,8}                # max 8 characters, at least 1 root, delimiter and brokerage
''', re.VERBOSE)
```

Comment: Thanks that's a good idea. Not perfect, because it'll match multiple periods even though only 1 is allowed, but much better than anything I could come up with

Comment: Doesn't applying quantifier {3,8} to a capture group, means the group needs to repeat minimum 3 times and max 8 times?

Comment: You're correct Matt.G. That's why I'm thinking of your answer but it's too hard to implement/ maintain. I think after getting the result he just need to check the length?

Answer (score 0):

It would be ideal to programatically check for the length constraints.

However, using Nested Conditional Regex, we could come up with the RIC regex as follows (please note that this could be a maintenance nightmare):

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TQu52P/2)

Regex:

```
^([A-Z0-9])?                                                                                                                # first character is [A-Z0-9] (capture group 1)
(?(1)                                                                                                                       # if capture group 1 is set
    \.[A-Za-z]{1,6} |                                                                                                       # then check if there is min 1 and max 6 chars after the dot (total 7, including dot 8)
    ([A-Z0-9]{2})?                                                                                                          # else check first 2 characters are [A-Z0-9] (capture group 2)
    (?(2)                                                                                                                   # if capture group 2 is set
        \.[A-Za-z]{1,5} |                                                                                                   # then check if there is min 1 and max 5 chars after the dot (total 7, including dot 8)
        ([A-Z0-9]{3})?
        (?(3)
            \.[A-Za-z]{1,4} |
            ([A-Z0-9]{4})?
            (?(4)
                \.[A-Za-z]{1,3} |
                ([A-Z0-9]{5})?
                (?(5)
                    \.[A-Za-z]{1,2} |
                    ([A-Z0-9]{6})?                                                                                          # else check first 6 characters are [A-Z0-9] (capture group 6)
                    (?(6)                                                                                                   # if capture group 6 is set
                        \.[A-Za-z] |                                                                                        # then check if there is 1 char after the dot (total 7, including dot 8)
                        ([A-Z0-9][a-z])?
                        (?(7)
                            \.[A-Za-z]{1,5} |
                            ([A-Z0-9][a-z]{2})?
                            (?(8)
                                \.[A-Za-z]{1,4} |
                                ([A-Z0-9][a-z]{3})?
                                (?(9)
                                    \.[A-Za-z]{1,3} |
                                    ([A-Z0-9][a-z]{4})?
                                    (?(10)
                                        \.[A-Za-z]{1,2} |
                                        ([A-Z0-9][a-z]{5})?
                                        (?(11)
                                            \.[A-Za-z] |
                                            ([A-Z0-9]{2}[a-z])?
                                            (?(12)
                                                \.[A-Za-z]{1,4} |
                                                ([A-Z0-9]{2}[a-z]{2})?
                                                (?(13)
                                                    \.[A-Za-z]{1,3} |
                                                    ([A-Z0-9]{2}[a-z]{3})?
                                                    (?(14)
                                                        \.[A-Za-z]{1,2} |
                                                        ([A-Z0-9]{2}[a-z]{4})?
                                                        (?(15)
                                                            \.[A-Za-z] |
                                                            ([A-Z0-9]{3}[a-z])?
                                                            (?(16)
                                                                \.[A-Za-z]{1,3} |
                                                                ([A-Z0-9]{3}[a-z]{2})?
                                                                (?(17)
                                                                    \.[A-Za-z]{1,2} |
                                                                    ([A-Z0-9]{3}[a-z]{3})?
                                                                    (?(18)
                                                                        \.[A-Za-z] |
                                                                        ([A-Z0-9]{4}[a-z])?
                                                                        (?(19)
                                                                            \.[A-Za-z]{1,2} |
                                                                            ([A-Z0-9]{4}[a-z]{2})?
                                                                            (?(20)
                                                                                \.[A-Za-z]  |
                                                                                ([A-Z0-9]{5}[a-z])?
                                                                                (?(21)
                                                                                    \.[A-Za-z]
                                                                                ) 
                                                                            ) 
                                                                        )
                                                                    ) 
                                                                ) 
                                                            )
                                                        ) 
                                                    ) 
                                                ) 
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Citing from the linked Wikipedia page: The Reuters Instrument Code

> For equities the codes were composed of a RIC Root (**one to four
>   characters – A through Z**), **followed by a period sign**, **then a one- or
>   two-character (A through Z)** code denoting the exchange on which the
>   instrument is traded. Each company was meant to have a unique RIC
>   root. Thus the RIC Root for International Business Machines would be
>   IBM irrespective of the exchange on which International Business
>   Machines was traded.     (highlighting added).

Therefore the pattern should look like this: `[A-Z]{1,4}\.[A-Z]{1,2}`

That's it.